# FIPS country codes in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, fips

I need to use FIPS country codes in my app.

Is there a way to find them?

I've tried NSLocaleCountryCode but these codes are different than FIPS.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FIPS` codes you're referring to are found easily using Google.    However, here are pointers to where you can locate them:

- [NGA Geopolitical Entities and Codes](http://earth-info.nga.mil/gns/html/gazetteers2.html)
- [Wikipedia Entry for FIPS 10-4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_10-4)
- [NIST FIPS 10-4 info](http://www.itl.nist.gov/fipspubs/fip10-4.htm)

Note that `FIPS` had been officially withdrawn for certain uses by the US Government, but that's probably not relevant to your particular use case.

Also, make sure you really need the FIPS codes, because they're quite similar to ISO country codes, but they are different and governed by different groups.

Comment: My app uses API which needs in certain cases these FIPS codes. So it seems I have to copy all these countries with codes into my app...

Comment: Yes, iOS does not have them built in.    If you found this answer helpful, please upvote and accept it.